# For what to use DAO classes and Service classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao, service-layer

I have read about DAO classes and Service classes but I don't understand for what are they used.
I have started a project in maven with spring and hibernate, and until now I have added in servlet.xml the configs for hibernate:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
              <value>com.fabbydesign.model.Useradmin</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The method from controller for login is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/do.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userLogin") LoginForm lf, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request){

    //bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "label.title"); - to add new message error
    logger.trace("showLogin - post");

    //check fields if the filds are filled and respects the size from beans
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        return "login";

    boolean userExists = loginService.checkLogin(lf.getUsername(), lf.getPassword());

    if(!userExists){
        bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "login.username.wrongUserOrPassword");
        return "login";
    }
    else{//set session
        request.getSession().setAttribute(adminSesName, true);
    }

    return "redirect:/admin/dashboard.html";
}
```

loginServiceImpl:

```
@Service("loginService")
```

public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

```
@Autowired
private LoginDAO loginDAO;

public void setLoginDAO(LoginDAO loginDAO) {
    this.loginDAO = loginDAO;
}

public Boolean checkLogin(String userName, String userPassword) {
    return loginDAO.checkLogin(userName, userPassword);
}
```

and loginDAOimpl:

```
@Repository("loginDAO")
```

public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO {

```
@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginDAOImpl.class);

public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {

    Boolean userFound = false;
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String sql = "from Useradmin where username = ?";
    Query<?> query = session.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(0, username);

    List<?> list = query.list();
    if ((list != null) && (list.size() == 1)) {
        Useradmin ua = (Useradmin) list.get(0);

        if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, ua.getPassword())) {
            userFound = true;
        }

    }
    return userFound;
}
```

So, what i should write in service classes and in DAO classes?
What i understand is that the code for manipulating data from database needs to stay in DAO classes, but services classes are for what?
Thanks!

Comment: service classes are for business logic

Comment: DAO - database layer, run queries for data

Comment: You can read these SO posts for the moment: [DAO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java) , [Service classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715105/what-is-the-service-class-in-programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to this simple example:

1.`PersonDao` only cares about database operation.

```
package com.pechen.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.pechen.entity.Person;

public interface PersonDao {

    public void save(Person p);

    public List<Person> list();

}
```

2.`PersonDaoImpl` is the implementation.

```
package com.pechen.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.pechen.entity.Person;

public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void save(Person p) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(p);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> list() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<Person> rst = session.createQuery("from person").getResultList();
        session.close();
        return rst;
    }

}
```

3. `PersonService` cares about the business logic, you can do anything you want before the database operation.

```
package com.pechen.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.pechen.dao.PersonDao;
import com.pechen.dao.PersonDaoImpl;
import com.pechen.entity.Person;

public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    public void setPersonDao(PersonDaoImpl personImpl) {
        this.personDao = personImpl;
    }

    public void savePerson(Person person) {
        // other business logic
        this.personDao.save(person);
        System.out.println("Save person successfully: " + person);
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        // other business logic
        return this.personDao.list();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the example, this is helpfull. so, from what i understand from your example, business logic, for example, gets data from DAO, and for example filter the data, or for example make some pagination here, and then retrive the data after the business logic is done, right? Is there a way to avoid adding this code: @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory; public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) { this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory; } to every service layer i have?for example to create a generic one and the rest to implement the generic?

Comment: Your understanding of business logic is properly right. The code you mentioned is in Dao layer, it may be hard to avoid this code block in this way. It can be if you don't use dependency injection.

Comment: ok, 10x. for example, i have this code in my controller, that i use to extract static data from an xml: context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("staticData/formFill.xml"); StudentFormDataBean sb (StudentFormDataBean)context.getBean("studentFormData"); return sb.getTypeOfStudies(); In this case i should choose the some logic like in your example: to create a service class and a dao class?

Comment: Yes, you can create a service and dao to manage business logic and db operation.

Answer (score 2):

DAO provides a connection to the DataBase and operations.

The service layer provides logic to operate on the data sent to and from the DAO.

Also security - If you have service layer that has no relation to the DB it is more difficult to gain access to the DB from the client except through the service.

Comment: sa, about DAO, i understand that it recieve and queries for data from database. and for what i understand, if i want to change the database (from mysql to oracle) i only have to change the daoIMPL classes?

Comment: im pretty sure your daoIMP is just interface, if you want to change your database in spring all you have to do is change database driver in application config and if you are usin ORM like hibernate u should change hibernates dialect from MySQLDialect to ORACLE etc.

Comment: if you are interested about implementation you can read this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074052/design-patterns/write-once--persist-anywhere.html its little bit old article but still helpful :)

Comment: the DAO should no really manage the connection to the database, it should use the connection suppose you have multiple tables that must be updated in a TX transaction....

Answer (score 1):

Service layer provides business operations and calling the DAO layer.

DAO layer is for the database layer. Meaning it performs data operations. This is where you put the retrieving of data, saving of data, and other database operations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be quite elaborate, so I will try to stick to some specifics here and will post links where ever necessary.

*For some groundwork,*

Layered and Tiered Architectures: You have to understand the difference between the Layers and Tiers of your application.

References:-
[What is the difference between tier vs layer application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978991/what-is-the-difference-between-tier-vs-layer-application)

[N-Tiered vs N-Layered architecture/design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182303/n-tiered-vs-n-layered-architecture-design)

So if you have three primary layers of your application: Presentation, Service, and Database, the Service Layer is the one where service classes are kept. This is a place to add the core business logic to your application. E.g. If you are developing a Ticketing Application using three layers, and you have a comprehensive Authentication functionality added to it then.

1. The web pages will be a part of the presentation layer.
2. The functionality like validation of the user-id, encryption check,
   timeout check etc will be a part of your service layer (Service
   Classes)
3. The connections to the DB and the respective interactions will be taken care of in the database layer (Hibernate)

Additionally:
The application architectures are not simply confined to three layered systems nowadays. There is an increased adoption of distributed application architectures where the Service Layer mentioned in point 2 above, is broken into multiple small services, each with their own database. (Keyword check: [Microservices](http://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html)). Also, they interact using messaging queues, but talking of all those things is not relevant to this question.

Recommended:
1. You go through the articles on the designing of service layers, and how different requirements lead to a different design of the Service Classes.
2. You read about design patterns like Providers, Factories, Singletons etc. which are commonly used in the designing of Services.

I hope I have answered your question.

**N.B: You need to tag your question with 'architecture' as it is more a question of Architecture than Java programming.**

Comment: 10x for your comment. how to tag my question? to add another tag with the name "architecture" ? But, after i understand about the DAO and the Service layer, i will ask about the code if is ok, and what to better, so ...the question will be about java programming :)

Comment: You can definitely ask about code... I will answer it to the best of my ability. You may have to post a different question for that perhaps. Also, I do not think that you will be able to add a tag to the question, neither will I. Just checked the meta and found that one needs to have 1500 privilege to add a tag.